# Dynamic Manipulation of Page content using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, web-applications, dom

I am a newbie and trying to make a simple dynamic page. which has contents in MySQL database, being fetched by php and stored in arrays. I am trying to generate the page based on the contents of these arrays using jQuery. I have pasted the code below and comments explain the stuff. It is not working please suggest me how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

```
    // execute query 
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $id[$i] = $row[0];$question[$i] = $row[1];$opt1[$i] = $row[2];$opt2[$i] = $row[3];$opt3[$i] = $row[4];$opt4[$i] = $row[5];$answer[$i] = $row[6];

        }
        mysql_free_result($result); 
    // close connection 
        mysql_close($con);  
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    //POPULATE THE JS ARRAY WITH DATA FROM SERVER   
        var Q = []; var op1 = [];   var op2 = [];   var op3 = [];   var op4 = [];   var ans = [];
        <?php $cnt = 1;?>
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            Q[i] = "<?php echo $question[$cnt] ?>";
            op1[i] = "<?php echo $opt1[$cnt] ?>";
            op2[i] = "<?php echo $opt2[$cnt] ?>";
            op3[i] = "<?php echo $opt3[$cnt] ?>";
            op4[i] = "<?php echo $opt4[$cnt] ?>";
            ans[i] = "<?php echo $answer[$cnt++] ?>";
        }

//IT WORKS FINE UPTO HERE 

    // TRYING TO DYNAMICALLY DISPLAY THE ARRAY CONTENTS ON THE WEB PAGE based upon clicks on the ids will match with the answer array is it the 
    // correct method to go about ??
    //
        $("document").ready(function() {
        for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        $("p").css("border", "3px solid red");
        $("#question").append(document.createTextNode(Q[i]));
        $("#op1").append(document.createTextNode(op1[i]));
        $("#op2").append(document.createTextNode(op2[i]));
        $("#op3").append(document.createTextNode(op3[i]));
        $("#op4").append(document.createTextNode(op4[i]));
          }
        });

    </script>

    </head>


    // FRAMEWORK OF The html content

    <body>
    <p class="q"></p>
    <p class="op1"></p>
    <p class="op2"></p>
    <p class="op3"></p>
    <p class="op4"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

// for outis, here is the code:

```
    var i = 1;
    $("#q").html(Q[i]);
    $("#op1").html(op1[i]);
    $("#op2").html(op2[i]);
    $("#op3").html(op3[i]);
    $("#op4").html(op4[i]);
        for(i=2;i<=10;i++){
            $("#q").html(Q[i]);
            $("#op1").html(op1[i]);
            $("#op2").html(op2[i]);
            $("#op3").html(op3[i]);
            $("#op4").html(op4[i]);
                    $('.set').clone(true).insertAfter('.set');
        }
```

Comment: You're using `#op1` when it should be `.op1`

Comment: Each JS array (`Q`, `ans`, `op*`) is filled with 10 copies of the same string, though the string may differ between arrays (e.g. `Q[3] == Q[7]`, `op1[1]` != op4[1]`). The arrays filling loop needs to be in the PHP code, not the Javascript.

Comment: 1) What's the query you're executing? Depending on what it is, changing the order of the columns in the table may cause the questions and answers to be disordered. 2) You should be fetching rows indexed associatively rather than numerically. 3) Depending on how `$i` is initialized, you might have an off-by-one error. Arrays should be indexed starting with 0 (array indices are the offset from the start, rather than the ordinal position of the array item).

Comment: The old mysql extension has been supplanted twice over. Use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) for new code. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html).

Comment: i deliberately removed the mysql part since i'm satisfied with the logic and working of the php code!

Comment: @gamebit07: [sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be self-contained. If you're going to remove some of the DB access code, remove it all and replace it with an array containing sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the ID/class disparity others have mentioned, there is no element with ID or class of "question", though there is a `<p class="q">`.

The PHP script is executed before the JS, so your loop to fill the JS arrays repeatedly fills them with the first values from the PHP arrays. The script that the browser executes is:

```
    var Q = []; var op1 = [];   var op2 = [];   var op3 = [];   var op4 = [];   var ans = [];
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        Q[i] = "[question 1, or possibly question 2]";
        op1[i] = "[option 1-1 ...]";
        op2[i] = "[option 1-2...]";
        op3[i] = "[option 1-3...]";
        op4[i] = "[option 1-4...]";
        ans[i] = "[answer 1 ...]";
    }
```

Instead, generate the array entirely in PHP:

```
var Q = [ <?php echo implode(', ', array_map('json_encode', $Q)); ?> ];
```

Rather than a separate array for each question component, a single array of question objects makes it easier to keep questions and choices together:

```
<?php
    // Fetching DB rows should be handled by a class or function that maps
    // DB rows to PHP objects, which is part of a data access layer, 
    // rather than where you generate HTML output, which belongs to the
    // presentation layer.
    // For this example, we use example data rather than the result of an SQL query.
    $questionQry = array(
        array('Question 1?', 'Choice 1 A', 'Choice 1 B', 'Choice 1 C', 'Choice 1 D'),
        array('Question 2?', 'Choice 2 A', 'Choice 2 B', 'Choice 2 C', 'Choice 2 D'),
        array('Question 3?', 'Choice 3 A', 'Choice 3 B', 'Choice 3 C', 'Choice 3 D'),
        array('Question 4?', 'Choice 4 A', 'Choice 4 B', 'Choice 4 C', 'Choice 4 D')
    );
    // encode data so it's suitable to be output as JS.
    // If you use PDO, you don't need to change this loop.
    foreach ($questionQry as $row) {
        $questions[] = json_encode(array( 
            'query' => $row[0],
            'choices' => array_slice($row, 1)
        ));
    }
?>
var questions = [ <?php echo implode(', ', $questions) ?> ];
```

Note this shows another advantage PDO has over the old mysql extension: query results can be looped over with [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach), just like arrays, since [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/PDOStatement) implements [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable). Thus you can switch between arrays for examples and SQL results for production code with a minimum of code rewriting.

The way your [HTML is structured](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/), once you fix the other problems the user will see all the questions, then all the first possible answers, then the second, &c. Instead, you could create an element that you can [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), then fill with content. Think structurally; an Question is a Query and some Choices, which are a list (an ordered one, at that). The HTML should reflect this.

```
<p id="QuestionTemplate" class="question" style="display: none">
    <div class="query"></div>
    <ol class="choices">
        <li><input type="radio" value="0" /><label></label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="1" /><label></label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="2" /><label></label></li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="3" /><label></label></li>
    </ol>
</p>
```

NB: slap a `.choices { list-style-type: upper-alpha; }` in your style sheet and answer choices are named A through D automatically.

To fill out the question template:

```
function renderQuestion(qstn, qid) {
    var $qElt = $('#QuestionTemplate').clone();
    $qElt.find('.query').attr('id', qid)
                           .text(qstn.query);
    $qElt.find('.choices').children().each(function (i, item) {
        item.find('input').attr({name: qid,
                                 id: qid+'_'+i});
        item.find('label').text(qstn.choices[i])
                          .attr('for', qid+'_'+i);
    }
}
$(function() {
    for (var i=0; i < Q.length; ++i) {
        renderQuestion(Q[i], 'q'+i);
    }
});
```

Or create the questions from scratch:

```
function renderQuestion(qstn, qid) {
    var qElt = document.createElement('p');
    qElt.id = 'Question_'+qid;

    var elt= document.createElement('div');
    elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(qstn.query));
    elt.className="query";
    qElt.appendChild(elt);

    elt = document.createElement('ol');
    elt.className="choices";
    for (var i=0; i < qstn.choices.length; ++i) {
        var choice = document.createElement('li');
        choice.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
        choice.lastChild.type='radio';
        choice.lastChild.name = qid;
        choice.lastChild.id = qid+'_'+i;
        choice.lastChild.value = i;

        choice.appendChild(document.createElement('label'));
        choice.lastChild.for = qid+'_'+i;
        choice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(qstn.choices[i]));

        elt.appendChild(choice);
    }
    qElt.appendChild(elt);
    document.appendChild(qElt);
}
```

In either case, the correct answers shouldn't be output when generating the JS.

Since you don't need JS to generate the questions, even better would be to generate the questions in PHP, which means you won't need to worry about what to do when JS isn't available.

```
<?php
    // Fetching DB rows should be handled by a class or function that maps
    // DB rows to PHP objects, which is part of the data access layer, 
    // rather than where you generate HTML output.
    // For this example, we just use example data.
    $questions = array(
        array('query' => 'Question 1?', 'A' => 'Choice 1 A', 'B' => 'Choice 1 B', 
                                          'C' => 'Choice 1 C', 'D' => 'Choice 1 D'),
        array('query' => 'Question 2?', 'A' => 'Choice 2 A', 'B' => 'Choice 2 B', 
                                          'C' => 'Choice 2 C', 'D' => 'Choice 2 D'),
        array('query' => 'Question 3?', 'A' => 'Choice 3 A', 'B' => 'Choice 3 B',
                                          'C' => 'Choice 3 C', 'D' => 'Choice 3 D'),
        array('query' => 'Question 4?', 'A' => 'Choice 4 A', 'B' => 'Choice 4 B', 
                                          'C' => 'Choice 4 C', 'D' => 'Choice 4 D')
    );
?>

<?php foreach ($query as $i => $q): ?>
  <p id="Question_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="question">
      <div class="query"><?php echo array_shift($q); </div>
      <ol class="choices">
        <?php foreach ($q as $j => $choice): ?>
          <li>
              <input type="radio" name="<?php echo "q$i"; ?>" id="<?php echo "q${i}_${j}"; ?>" value="<?php echo $j; ?>" />
              <label for="<?php echo "q${i}_${j}; ?>"><?php echo $choice; </label>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ol>
  </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i filled the array as u said, works fine, tried the clone this way : var i = 1;
 $("#q").html(Q[i]);
 $("#op1").html(op1[i]);
 $("#op2").html(op2[i]);
 $("#op3").html(op3[i]);
 $("#op4").html(op4[i]);
  for(i=2;i<=10;i++){
   $("#q").html(Q[i]);
   $("#op1").html(op1[i]);
   $("#op2").html(op2[i]);
   $("#op3").html(op3[i]);
   $("#op4").html(op4[i]);
  }
  $('.set').clone(true).insertAfter(".set");   but this does not seem to work .let me know what went wrong, thanks!

Comment: @gamebit07: the same thing that was going wrong before. A hash ("#") in a selector identifies an element by ID, but you don't have any elements with the IDs you're selecting. Use class (prefixed with a dot) and element selectors. Code in comments are unreadable. If you're posting changed code, you can add an addendum to your question.

Comment: well, i donot know hot to, manpulate the radio contents, instead i created the <p id="question"> and the same for four options. i have added the code, and you can see. Could you please also answer how to manipulate the contents of the <div class="answers"> using my pre-filled arrays. Thanks!

Comment: @gamebit07: for one thing, you need to create the clone before you set the question & answer text. For another, IDs need to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to why you want to run your output via jquery. Seems like uncessary overengineering to me. Why can't you just filter the db output straight to your page or am I missing something?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_quiz.asp i'm trying to give the same kind of look, the only difference being that, click on the div would do the trick instead of radio form, and adding radio listeners.

Answer (score 0):

your selectors in the jquery are looking for id's...

```
$("#op4").append(document.createTextNode(op4[i]));
```

^ is looking for an id of 'op4' whereas your markup has the fifth paragraph with a class of 'op4'...

```
<p class="op4"></p>
```

maybe try changing either the jquery or markup so that the selectors match.

Not sure if this is an oversight a fresh pair of eyes might have caught here. Good Luck fixing!

Comment: thnx for the info, fixed it still it is not working. im trying to give it a look as follows :http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_quiz.asp could u tell me how to go abt??

Answer (score 0):

And every question will be overwritten by the next one. You'll only see the last.

Comment: yes you are write, cloning removes the above problem, but the issue still remains, i want one question at a time, how can that be made possible, please let me know! thnx!